# Why does $\mathbf{A}(x) = \frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{B}(x) \times \mathbf{x})$ work?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, gauge

In my textbook, the identity for a possible vector potential
$$\mathbf{A}(x) = \frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{B}(x) \times \mathbf{x})$$ is used. How is this valid? If I compute the curl, I get
$$\mathbf{B}(x) \equiv \nabla \times \mathbf{A}(x) = \frac{1}{2}\left({\bf{x}} \cdot \nabla {\bf{B}} - \left( {\nabla  \cdot {\bf{B}}} \right){\bf{x}} + \left( {\nabla  \cdot {\bf{x}}} \right){\bf{B}} - {\bf{B}} \cdot \nabla {\bf{x}}
\right) = \frac{1}{2}\left({\bf{x}} \cdot \nabla {\bf{B}} + 3{\bf{B}} - {\bf{B}} \cdot \nabla {\bf{x}}
\right)$$
but I can't see how the RHS equals $\bf{B}$?

Comment: (1) Its true only for position independent B. so gradB is 0.
(2) x is the component of the position vector that is perpendicular to the direction of B. Other component drops out when you take cross product in the first place. So B.grad x is 0.

Comment: Just for reference, this is called the 'symmetric gauge'.

Comment: @Mauricio Did not know that (just looked it up), thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This identity holds only for a **uniform** magnetic field $\vec B$. Many terms cancel in your formula. It remains
$$\eqalign{
   \vec\nabla\times\vec A
   &={1\over 2}\big((\vec\nabla.\vec x)\vec B-(\vec B.\vec\nabla)\vec x\big)\cr
   &={1\over 2}\big(3\vec B-\vec B\big)\cr
   &=\vec B\cr
   }$$
as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your very nice answer! I just had one last question: why is ${\bf{B}} \cdot \nabla {\bf{x}} = {\bf{B}}$?

Comment: @EE18.  $\vec{B}\cdot\vec{x}$ is the directional derivative along the direction of $\vec{B}$ times the length of $\vec{B}$. The directional derivative of the position vector is just the unit vector along that direction (e.g., consider the directional derivative along the $y$-direction, i.e., $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\vec{x}=\hat{y}$.

Comment: $(\vec{B}\cdot \nabla )\vec{x}$ is meant I suppose? @march But that makes sense, thank you!

Comment: @EE18 Yeah, typo.  You got it.